# Spark Scala - Column Names difference using different Scala versions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, select, schema, version

I am trying to run countDistinct(colname) then it is having schema differene which is failing into Scala version 2.12 . SelectExp is failing due to this .Do i need to make code changes or any other  option which i enable to make it compatible with high version.

Scala 2.12 :-

root
|--count(colname)

Scala 2.11

[image: 2]

root
|--count(Distinct colname)

Comment: Please post text rather than images, and try to provide a minimal code example and the error messages in the two cases.

Comment: Please provide some sample code. It is not really possible to say if you need to make code changes if we don't what what the code looks like! And if this relates to apache Spark then please add the appropriate tag and make this clear in the question.